# Website images blurry in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am struggling with this next bit:

All the images on our website look very blurry in IE.

I first had the problem all images look very blurry on all windows devices, then I increased the resolution of the images, and now it is showing the blurry images on IE only.

Any clue what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resizing images that are small.
This is the original image: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sHh3.png)

It is 300 x 224 pixel long and you are resizing it to 600 x 448.
You are loosing quallity by making a small image bigger.
You should have a big image that doesn't need to scaled or just a big image that will be escaled to a lower size.